# ¿Tengo un error 405 al obtener un json local usando ajax?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy tratando de llenar un etiqueta `select` desde un archivo json al ejecutar el ajax me sale el siguiente error `method not allowed error 405` esta llamando un json local.

Y no encuentro la forma de obtener los datos de mi json.

Método

```
function get_countries_list() {
    var d1 = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/app/connect/get_paises/ajax.json",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            d1.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            d1.reject(new Error(errorMessage));
        }
    });
    return d1.promise();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo ajax

```
[{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf6","id":34,"nombre":"Alemania","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cd9","id":1,"nombre":"Argentina","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf2","id":30,"nombre":"Australia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf3","id":31,"nombre":"Austria","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cdb","id":5,"nombre":"Bolivia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cda","id":2,"nombre":"Brasil","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d00","id":54,"nombre":"Bulgaria","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cff","id":53,"nombre":"B\u00e9lgica","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ceb","id":23,"nombre":"Canada","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d17","id":1007,"nombre":"Chile","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cfe","id":52,"nombre":"China","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cdc","id":8,"nombre":"Colombia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0d","id":68,"nombre":"Corea","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce2","id":14,"nombre":"Costa Rica","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d01","id":56,"nombre":"Croacia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf1","id":29,"nombre":"Cuba","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf5","id":33,"nombre":"Dinamarca","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cdd","id":9,"nombre":"Ecuador","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce3","id":15,"nombre":"El Salvador","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d14","id":75,"nombre":"Emiratos Arabes","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d10","id":71,"nombre":"Escocia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d02","id":57,"nombre":"Eslovaquia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d03","id":58,"nombre":"Eslovenia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce9","id":21,"nombre":"Espa\u00f1a","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cec","id":24,"nombre":"Estados Unidos","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d04","id":59,"nombre":"Estonia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"5a04b9523b96b4e8b32ad72e","id":2000,"nombre":"Filipinas","status":1,"created":1510244446},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d05","id":60,"nombre":"Finlandia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ced","id":25,"nombre":"Francia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf7","id":35,"nombre":"Grecia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce4","id":16,"nombre":"Guatemala","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d18","id":370,"nombre":"Haiti","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cfa","id":38,"nombre":"Holanda","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce5","id":17,"nombre":"Honduras","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d06","id":61,"nombre":"Hungria","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d07","id":62,"nombre":"India","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf4","id":32,"nombre":"Inglaterra","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d15","id":1000,"nombre":"Internacional","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d13","id":74,"nombre":"Irak","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d08","id":63,"nombre":"Irlanda","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cfc","id":40,"nombre":"Israel","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cee","id":26,"nombre":"Italia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"5ff72a2bf3f4532a60bda49f","id":2003,"nombre":"Jamaica","status":1,"created":1610033041},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cfb","id":39,"nombre":"Japon","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d09","id":64,"nombre":"Letonia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0a","id":65,"nombre":"Lituania","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d19","id":380,"nombre":"Malasia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce6","id":18,"nombre":"Mexico","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce7","id":19,"nombre":"Nicaragua","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0b","id":66,"nombre":"Noruega","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0c","id":67,"nombre":"Nueva Zelanda","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce8","id":20,"nombre":"Panama","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cde","id":10,"nombre":"Paraguay","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cdf","id":11,"nombre":"Peru","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cfd","id":50,"nombre":"Polonia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cea","id":22,"nombre":"Portugal","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cef","id":27,"nombre":"Puerto Rico","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"614209e8b4a58303a051e5b6","id":2005,"nombre":"Reino Unido","status":1,"created":1631717662},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d11","id":200,"nombre":"Republica Checa","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf0","id":28,"nombre":"Republica Dominicana","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d16","id":1001,"nombre":"Rep\u00fablica de Malta","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0e","id":69,"nombre":"Rumania","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf9","id":37,"nombre":"Rusia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d0f","id":70,"nombre":"Singapur","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8d12","id":73,"nombre":"Suecia","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8cf8","id":36,"nombre":"Suiza","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"5b9816882afa097a77240e0b","id":2001,"nombre":"Tailandia","status":1,"created":1536691116},{"_id":"602ed43c649f302e90d1d59d","id":2004,"nombre":"Trinidad y Tobago","status":1,"created":1613681715},{"_id":"5d67c5e72afa09c27f5034cf","id":2002,"nombre":"Ucrania","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce0","id":12,"nombre":"Uruguay","status":1,"created":1474945682},{"_id":"57e9e292820cbfd37f0b8ce1","id":13,"nombre":"Venezuela","status":1,"created":1474945682}]
```

Comment: No sería mejor usar un GET?

Comment: Eso sería mejor pero el código que se esta manejando se llena de esa manera

Comment: A ver, reformulo. Estás usando `type: 'POST',` y yo pregunto si no puedes hacer `type: 'GET',`

Comment: ah ok entendí mal, lo probare

Comment: @Alfabravo ese era la solución muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener datos del servidor debes utilizar una petición GET

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/app/connect/get_paises/ajax.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
            d1.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            d1.reject(new Error(errorMessage));
        }
});
```

Comment: ese era la solución muchas gracias.